# Android kotlin - trouble with basic math to resize bitmap

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I got this code:

```
        var newheight = 1000
        if(myBitmap.height > newheight){
            var aspect = myBitmap.height / myBitmap.width
            Log.d("letsSee", "width: " + myBitmap.width + " height: " + myBitmap.height) // letsSee: width: 2592 height: 1458

            var newwidth = newheight * aspect
            Log.d("letsSee", "newwidth: " + newwidth + " aspect: " + aspect) // newwidth: 0 aspect: 0

            myBitmap = createScaledBitmap (myBitmap, newwidth, newheight,false)
        }
```

The app crashes this way, what's wrong here? I also tried to add `.toInt()`:

```
            var newwidth = newheight * aspect.toInt()

            myBitmap = createScaledBitmap (myBitmap, newwidth.toInt(), newheight,false)
```

..

Comment: Nope it's 2592..

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Is `myBitmap` coming in as `null`?

Comment: No because I do facedetection and more with it, everything works fine when I don't try to resize myBitmap first

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rounding error:

```
var aspect = myBitmap.height / myBitmap.width
```

When you divide 1458 / 2592 it's 0.5625, but both variables are `int` so is the `aspect` variable. In result, it's rounded down to 0.

You need to calculate your expression as floats (cast at least 1 variable to float to implicitly change resulting type):

```
var aspect = myBitmap.height / myBitmap.width.toFloat()
```

Your aspect should be about 0.5625 now. Then cast down to `int` when calculating width in pixels:

```
var newwidth = (newheight * aspect).toInt()
```

Comment: Yes now it works, thanks! dealing with such awful nonsense makes me wish to work with javascript :( why the hell is there something like float long int instead just one format for all damn numbers like in javascript/PHP

Comment: @donkinged I'm personally a huge fan of strong typed languages. This was just a mistake with type inferring; If You change your `aspect` declaration into `var aspect : Float` IDE would error out your `Int` division on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `var aspect = myBitmap.height / myBitmap.width`

In kotlin, when you divide an integer by an integer, the result is rounded off to an integer.

First of all, as per your use case the aspect = width / height

Moreover, as you are getting the result as an integer, if the resultant is say 0.5, `aspect` will have value ZERO, as it is an integer. The app is crashing because newwidth is becoming zero.

Please change the line to

`val aspect = myBitmap.width.toFloat() / myBitmap.height.toFloat()`

And use `newwidth.toInt()` while calling `createScaledBitmap`.

P.S. Please don''t mind my grammar.

Comment: `myBitmap.width` and `myBitmap.height` both are integers, that's why the resultant is an integer.